# Can I splice a ground wire from old wiring to a GFCI outlet?

Tags: gfci

After pulling out the old medicine cabinet in my bathroom, I found that the "new" GFCI outlet that was installed in the bathroom is not actually grounded.  The ground wire was just hanging loose.  Can I splice a ground wire from the ground wire in the existing wiring to the ground wire on the GFCI?  Or should I even worry about that and just leave the ground wire as is and not attached to anything else?

Comment: Did you have a professional install this outlet in the first place?  That wire should be attached to the greenish lookin straight blade screw connection...for a 3 wire set.  This ground takes it back to the breaker box.  This box is connected a big copper rod driven into the ground for the entire house.  You do not want odds 'n end grounding rods in your home.  You really should find out who and when and why electrical stuff was amended, worked upon or upgraded.  If not by a LICENSED electrician and it causes a fire your insurance will not cover your home.  Check this stuff out now...not after

Comment: you can label the GFCI as "no equipment ground" and keep it as is.

Comment: The outlet was installed by the previous owner.  I know she paid someone to do it but I'm not sure who.  I have contacted her for the name of the installer but have not heard back from her yet.

Answer (score 2):

GFCI's don't actually require a ground wire, so it is legal to continue as-is.

Attaching the ground wire is *worse than useless* unless the ground wire you're attaching is actually connected to the house's grounding system.  So that's worth checking.  I would look for zero-ohm resistance between the ground wire and nearby water pipes, if they are metal.

Comment: Legal?  Not if done by anyone other than a licensed electrician.  That is why electricians have to charge so much.  If it is because they screwed up then their insurance will cover YOUR HOME.  If some 'friend' does a favor and the house burns down you are totally screwed.  Most buildings and code officials will fine you if you've had electrical work done by an unlicensed electrician.  Fact.  Not worth the savings...trust me.

Comment: Welcome to diy.se.  This comes up from time to time, and it's discussed here.  http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/hire-a-professional-answers/1164#1164  Your claim will be surprising to many on this forum; it would help if you can cite code sections, case law etc.

Comment: @stormy that's not necessarily true, in lots of places homeowners are allowed to do their own electrical work. As long as the work is permitted and inspected, there's not a problem. Typically the homeowner must have a certain amount of liability insurance, but that's dependant on the local government.

Comment: @stormy, **utterly untrue**.

Comment: Just a note for the OP: the GFCI isn't any safer in terms of electrical shock if it's grounded (GFCI's do occasionally fail, though). It's legal without grounding, but if you plug equipment into it that really requires a ground connection it may not be completely safe for that equipment. The GFCI receptacle and all downstream receptacles should be labeled "No Equipment Ground" if they are not grounded.

Comment: Are you telling me that insurance companies don't care who does the work?  Where do you guys live?  This was a very big deal in Washington State.  Remember when low voltage was regulated?  Only low voltage certified electricians could do the work, at least the transformers the rest if purchased from Home Depot as a kit was...ok to do...anything else, well, you are saying where you live it is ok for homeowners to install, upgrade or fix?  Even though I know bonafide people with electricity, even they couldn't afford to help out a friend.  Without a license no one would touch improvements.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Please tell me what is utterly untrue.  I would never tell someone that the entire subject they were discussing was utterly untrue and leave it at that.  What I am saying is totally true in Washington State.  I built custom homes for 9 years and designed/installed landscapes for 30 as a L.S. Architect.  Dealing with electrical issues every project. GFI's aren't the 'bee's knees' either.  But why totally untrue...I'd love to make sure I know that what I say is true.  Or at least what it is I need to learn...to make what I say true.  Makes a difference WHERE the OP lives...

Comment: My boss knew electrical very well and always did his own (fixes) and all of the low voltage work.  Then there was a new rule for low voltage and a couple of months to become licensed just to do low voltage.  Let me tell you he studied and took that test at least 6 or 7 times to get his license during the few months allowed.  This is low voltage we are talking about.  In Washington state, if you have a dang fire because of electricity and you didn't have a licensed electrician, your insurance would not pay anything.  Oh, and same in Oregon btw.  This was such a big deal.  Please explain please!

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Please tell me why whatever I said was untrue.  It is true that I have been out of the 'field' for a bit of time to be called RUSTY.

Comment: @stormy in this online community, we do not simply repeat opinions or get defensive.  A person making a claim needs to be ready to **back up the claim with a reference to code or state law** when that opinion is called into question. The next step is for you to do that.   And yes, sometimes the person making the claim goes "y'know what guys, I looked all over to try to back it up, but I just couldn't find anything to support my claim, looks like I made an error."  And when that happens, it's no big deal.   Done it a few times myself.

Comment: No problem...I totally get that.  I am hedging on the safe side that I know.  I would hope my comments would prompt the OP to look up their own codes and rules.  I am not saying 'DO THIS'...I am sure you must see that.  I love being called on 'the carpet' so I am able to learn something new and definitely test my own foundation of knowledge.  Without personal observation and experience this forum would be moot.  Anyone can go out and find information to use, it is just knowing what is right and what is wrong.

Comment: @Harper Amazing you think I am being defensive.  Really.  I work so hard to be nice and correct with my assumptions.  You'll see, I have NO PROBLEM saying opps, I am wrong you are right.  None at all.  I am answering questions knowing I don't know everything.  Just giving of my own time, money and experience so that if I am wrong I LEARN something and correct my own foundation.  If I have to use the internet...I shall to illustrate a point.  No problem. But I should be able to  give a reasonable explanation without.

Comment: @Stormy, sorry if my comment was blunt. Please state where NFPA 70 or other code says that a homeowner is not allowed to perform simple receptacle replacement. You stated it as "Fact". PS, you *are* coming across as defensive, your repeated long comments remind me of my rambling crazy uncle who is on a 3-day psych hold right now.

Comment: Rambling.  Sigh. I am bouncing between two different questions.  This is getting even weirder.  Your rambling crazy uncle is not me.  You might just be super sensitized.  I need to know where the heck jurisdiction this is taking place.  My entire point is to alert the OP that DIY in electricity IS NOT A GOOD IDEA AT ALL.   How the heck does my verbiage translate to a crazy uncle?  I am just trying to HELP this OP to have the motivation to find the dang rules, regulations so that he isn't invalidating his oh so expensive home owner's insurance.  Is there an electrician here to comment?